# I used the Buddypress Message Compose to send a site wide email to all members wasnt sent tho

Tags: buddypress, email

I used the Buddypress Message Compose to send a site wide email to all members wasnt sent though.  Where would I look to see why messages were not delivered to all site members of my buddypress wp site?  Can I configure this to use smpt instead?

I researched this some and found others have had similar problems with the "send to all" from the buddypress message compose screen but couldn't find solutions.

I am thinking it may have something to do with the wp config file and how emails configured?

Thanks

Comment: I send a message to one member and theres a checkbox to send to all. I checked that and it didn't go to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the feature works is by posting the message on the screen, not in the members inbox, and it requires the template tag:

```
<?php bp_message_get_notices(); ?>
```

So wherever you put the tag, the message will appear there. In the default buddypress theme, it shows up when you activate a message and the user is logged in, right below the log out link in the sidebar login form.

To send inbox messages through buddypress, you can search for the Mass Messaging plugin.

Comment: Thank you!
I would like to be able to message everyone in their inbox and or just BP Group Admins.